# How to disable the tooltip when row dragging in ag-grid?

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, ag-grid

I have an ag-grid table within my Angular 5 application. When dragging rows this tooltip appears (example below from the official ag-grid guide):

[image: Drag and drop tooltip]

How do I disable this tooltip entirely, or at least hide the text?

Answer (score 1):

You can hide it entirely using some CSS:

```
.ag-dnd-ghost {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, currently, `ag-grid` doesn't provide a way to modify existing approach with `drag&drop`.

*only to fork the `lib` and modify `source` files.